# rosjava tutorial 4.2 failed

Tags: raspberrypi, ros-kinetic, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava_build_tools/Tutorials/indigo/Creating%20Rosjava%20Packages#Library_Project_.28Jar.29
I tried [4.2 Library Project (Jar)].
error by catkin_make

> ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cd src/rosjava_catkin_package_a<br>
> ubuntu@ubuntu:~/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a$ catkin_create_rosjava_library_project rosjava_gradle_subproject_a
> ubuntu@ubuntu:~/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a$ cd ../..<br>
> ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ catkin_make
> Base path: /home/ubuntu
> Source space: /home/ubuntu/src
> Build space: /home/ubuntu/build
> Devel space: /home/ubuntu/devel
> Install space: /home/ubuntu/install
> ####
> #### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/ubuntu/build"
> ####
> -- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/ubuntu/devel
> -- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/ubuntu/rosjava/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
> -- This workspace overlays: /home/ubuntu/rosjava/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
> -- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
> -- Using Debian Python package layout
> -- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
> -- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
> -- Call enable_testing()
> -- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/ubuntu/build/test_results
> -- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
> -- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
> -- catkin 0.7.8
> -- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
> -- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> -- ~~  traversing 2 packages in topological order:
> -- ~~  - rosjava_catkin_package_a
> -- ~~  - rosjava_catkin_package_b
> -- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> -- +++ processing catkin package: 'rosjava_catkin_package_a'
> -- ==> add_subdirectory(rosjava_catkin_package_a)
> -- +++ processing catkin package: 'rosjava_catkin_package_b'
> -- ==> add_subdirectory(rosjava_catkin_package_b)
> -- Configuring done
> -- Generating done
> -- Build files have been written to: /home/ubuntu/build
> ####
> #### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/ubuntu/build"
> ####
> [100%] Gradling tasks for rosjava_catkin_package_a
> warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Talker.java:19: error: package org.ros.concurrent does not exist
> import org.ros.concurrent.CancellableLoop;
>                          ^
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Talker.java:20: error: package org.ros.namespace does not exist
> import org.ros.namespace.GraphName;
>                         ^
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Talker.java:21: error: package org.ros.node does not exist
> import org.ros.node.AbstractNodeMain;
>                    ^
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Talker.java:22: error: package org.ros.node does not exist
> import org.ros.node.ConnectedNode;
>                    ^
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Talker.java:23: error: package org.ros.node does not exist
> import org.ros.node.NodeMain;
>                    ^
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Talker.java:24: error: package org.ros.node.topic does not exist
> import org.ros.node.topic.Publisher;
>                          ^
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Talker.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
> public class Talker extends AbstractNodeMain {
>                             ^
>   symbol: class AbstractNodeMain
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Talker.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
>   public GraphName getDefaultNodeName() {
>          ^
>   symbol:   class GraphName
>   location: class Talker
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Talker.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
>   public void onStart(final ConnectedNode connectedNode) {
>                             ^
>   symbol:   class ConnectedNode
>   location: class Talker
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Listener.java:19: error: package org.apache.commons.logging does not exist
> import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
>                                  ^
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Listener.java:20: error: package org.ros.message does not exist
> import org.ros.message.MessageListener;
>                       ^
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Listener.java:21: error: package org.ros.namespace does not exist
> import org.ros.namespace.GraphName;
>                         ^
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Listener.java:22: error: package org.ros.node does not exist
> import org.ros.node.AbstractNodeMain;
>                    ^
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Listener.java:23: error: package org.ros.node does not exist
> import org.ros.node.ConnectedNode;
>                    ^
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Listener.java:24: error: package org.ros.node does not exist
> import org.ros.node.NodeMain;
>                    ^
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Listener.java:25: error: package org.ros.node.topic does not exist
> import org.ros.node.topic.Subscriber;
>                          ^
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Listener.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
> public class Listener extends AbstractNodeMain {
>                               ^
>   symbol: class AbstractNodeMain
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Listener.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
>   public GraphName getDefaultNodeName() {
>          ^
>   symbol:   class GraphName
>   location: class Listener
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Listener.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
>   public void onStart(ConnectedNode connectedNode) {
>                       ^
>   symbol:   class ConnectedNode
>   location: class Listener
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Talker.java:31: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>   @Override
>   ^
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Talker.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
>     return GraphName.of("rosjava/talker");
>            ^
>   symbol:   variable GraphName
>   location: class Talker
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Talker.java:36: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>   @Override
>   ^
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Talker.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
>     final Publisher publisher =
>           ^
>   symbol:   class Publisher
>   location: class Talker
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Talker.java:38: error: package std_msgs does not exist
>     final Publisher publisher =
>                             ^
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Talker.java:39: error: package std_msgs does not exist
>         connectedNode.newPublisher("chatter", std_msgs.String._TYPE);
>                                                       ^
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Talker.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
>     connectedNode.executeCancellableLoop(new CancellableLoop() {
>                                              ^
>   symbol:   class CancellableLoop
>   location: class Talker
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Listener.java:32: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>   @Override
>   ^
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Listener.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
>     return GraphName.of("rosjava/listener");
>            ^
>   symbol:   variable GraphName
>   location: class Listener
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Listener.java:37: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>   @Override
>   ^
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Listener.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
>     final Log log = connectedNode.getLog();
>           ^
>   symbol:   class Log
>   location: class Listener
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Listener.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
>     Subscriber subscriber = connectedNode.newSubscriber("chatter", std_msgs.String._TYPE);
>     ^
>   symbol:   class Subscriber
>   location: class Listener
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Listener.java:40: error: package std_msgs does not exist
>     Subscriber subscriber = connectedNode.newSubscriber("chatter", std_msgs.String._TYPE);
>                        ^
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Listener.java:40: error: package std_msgs does not exist
>     Subscriber subscriber = connectedNode.newSubscriber("chatter", std_msgs.String._TYPE);
>                                                                                             ^
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Listener.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
>     subscriber.addMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
>                                       ^
>   symbol:   class MessageListener
>   location: class Listener
> /home/ubuntu/src/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/src/main/java/com/github/rosjava_catkin_package_a/rosjava_gradle_subproject_a/Listener.java:41: error: package std_msgs does not exist
>     subscriber.addMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
>                                                               ^
> 35 errors
> 1 warning
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':rosjava_gradle_subproject_a:compileJava'.
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>
> * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> rosjava_catkin_package_a/CMakeFiles/gradle-rosjava_catkin_package_a.dir/build.make:57: recipe for target 'rosjava_catkin_package_a/CMakeFiles/gradle-rosjava_catkin_package_a' failed
> make[2]: *** [rosjava_catkin_package_a/CMakeFiles/gradle-rosjava_catkin_package_a] Error 1
> CMakeFiles/Makefile2:363: recipe for target 'rosjava_catkin_package_a/CMakeFiles/gradle-rosjava_catkin_package_a.dir/all' failed
> make[1]: *** [rosjava_catkin_package_a/CMakeFiles/gradle-rosjava_catkin_package_a.dir/all] Error 2
> Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
> make: *** [all] Error 2
> Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277454/rosjava-tutorial-4.2-failed/) by [ramekabi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32877/ramekabi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-12-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2017-12-06**:
Did you do step 4.1 before 4.2, or did you go straight to 4.2?
I can't reproduce that on my side, but the error seems to be that catkin didn't find the core dependencies. That shouldn't happen after sourcing `~/rosjava/devel/setup.bash` (or wherever you installed rosjava)

**Comment by [ramekabi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32877/ramekabi/) on 2017-12-06**:
I did 4.1 before 4.2 . 
And I did [source ~/rosjava/devel/setup.bash].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are using your home folder as workspace; that doesn't sound right. In the tutorial it's implicit, but in ROS you usually place the `src` inside a workspace folder.

So create a workspace folder where you place everything before proceeding. You should create the packages inside something like `~/my_rosjava_ws/src`, and not just `~/src`.

Let me know if it works that way; maybe that tutorial needs this clarification.

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2017-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ramekabi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32877/ramekabi/) on 2017-12-06**:
I tried tutorial that created a workspace.
But, same error occurred.
By the way, I use ROS on the RaspberryPi3. Is this the cause?

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2017-12-07**:
when you source your rosjava workspace, all those classes should be available for you. Go to ~/rosjava/devel/share/maven. Do you see folders with JAR files with the artifacts for rosjava_core?

**Comment by [ramekabi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32877/ramekabi/) on 2017-12-09**:
Sorry, I cannot understand what you say. Please tell me a command that I should do.

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/rosjava/devel/share/maven/org/ros$ ls

rosjava_bootstrap  rosjava_core  rosjava_messages

**Comment by [ramekabi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32877/ramekabi/) on 2017-12-09**:
Sorry, I cannot understand what you say. Please tell me a command that I should do.

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/rosjava/devel/share/maven/org/ros$ ls

rosjava_bootstrap  rosjava_core  rosjava_messages

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2017-12-11**:
It's a bit hard to tell what your problem is exactly.
Does this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava_build_tools/Tutorials/indigo/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28Java%29 (creating publisher/ subscriber) work for you?